# Mocha multiple test in order

Tags: mocha.js

Mocha multiple test in order

I am writting test with mocha like this

```
describe('application', function(){

    describe('First set of test', function(){

      var socket;

      before(function(done) {
        var opts = {
          'reconnection delay' : 0,
          'reopen delay' : 0,
          'forceNew' : true
        };
        socketio = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, opts);

        done();

        socketio.on('connect', function() {
          console.log('worked...');
        });

        socketio.on('disconnect', function() {
          console.log('disconnected...');
        })

      });

      it('first test should be true', function(done){
        expect(variable_one).to.be.false;
        done();
      });

      it('second test should be true', function(done){
        client.hget(hash, "status", function(err, result){
          expect(variable_two).to.be.true;
          done();
        })
      });

      it('thrid test should be true', function(done){
        client.hget(hash, "status", function(err, result){
          expect(variable_three).to.be.true;
          done();
        })
      });
  });
});
```

What I need is that test should be nested in order, to set the before variables is not enough because the third test depends on the second and the second on the first one. With the done variable are all running in parallel.
Is there a posible way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Mocha is not designed for imposing a dependency among *tests*. Usually, when someone says they want an order to their tests, there's a way to solve the issue without actually imposing an order but what the solution is depends on the specific problem. The code you have in your question does not run (`client` is never set, to name just one problem) and is not very meaningful (it is unclear what the tests are supposed to test) so it is not clear what would be best in your situation.

Comment: @Louis Thank you for your comment. Suppose I want to order my test because I want to check the the state of the variables in the workflow. The state is save in a redis and I want to check that the transitions are ok.